# Htaccess RewriteRule width folder : not found

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a problem with my htaccess file.

Some rules are OK, like this one :

```
  RewriteRule ^page\.htm$ /page-source.php [L]
```

But this one :

```
  RewriteRule ^folder/$ /page-source.php [L]
```

Does not work, the error is a 404 not found.
Someone got an idea of the problem ?

The idea is to show the page www.mydomain.com/page-source.php when we ask www.mydomaine.com/folder/

Thank you.

Comment: Mmm, can you try it without the `/`, i.e.: `RewriteRule ^folder/$ page-source.php [L]` Pls let me know if that does anything. :)

Comment: Thank you zx81, i tried it, it do nothing... same error, 404... very strange

The htaccess file look like this :

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^page\.htm$ /page-source.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^folder/$ /page-source.php [L]

Comment: It's now ok, the solution was to add Options -Multiviews at the beginning of the htaccess... thank you